# JUnit 5 parallel tests not running in junit-platform.properties file

Tags: java, maven, junit, autotest

The tests do not run in parallel, "Unused property" is written in the properties file, what could be the problem? POM:

https://gist.github.com/vindus940/60b1a6440d3be9f25ff2b00f0e74dcea

file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you, including Intellij reporting the properties in `junit-platform.properties` as not being used.

Adding the JUnit properties to my `build.gradle` ended up being the solution for me.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled', 'true'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy', 'dynamic'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default', 'concurrent'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default', 'concurrent'
    }
}
```